# Using Dualshock 3 controller via USB (no Bluetooth)

Tags: usb, gamepad, ps3

I am trying to use a DualShock 3 controller via USB, but I cannot get any input from it. I followed the Ubuntu guide with qtsixa, but it said I needed Bluetooth. My computer has no Bluetooth adapter, and I don't feel like buying a dongle. Does anyone know of an alternative, USB-only method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it via USB, just plug it. It should work out of the box. One problem you will however run into is that every button on the controller is reported as both analog and digital, which confuses a lot of games.

To work around that you can try xboxdrv (support PS3 controller as well, despite the name):

- http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/